# How to Bridge an existing Swift Module with View into React-Native?

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

I already get the module working with Bridge, but i don't know how to call a SWIFT view inside the React-Native.

I got this error:  whose view is not in the window hierarchy! at XCODE Log!

Using React-Native 0.61.2

Trying to port the module MercadoPagoSDK: https://github.com/mercadopago/px-ios

Tried bridging the module, but the UI View, is not appearing, get error in XCODE log;    whose view is not in the window hierarchy! at XCODE Log!

```
import MercadoPagoSDK
import UIKit


@objc(MercadoPago)
class MercadoPago: UIView {
  @objc  func getPayment(_ publicKey : NSString,preferenceId : NSString,callback: RCTResponseSenderBlock) -> Void {
      //callback([count])

    let checkout = MercadoPagoCheckout.init(builder: MercadoPagoCheckoutBuilder.init(publicKey: publicKey as String, preferenceId: preferenceId as String))

    checkout.start(navigationController: UIViewController)

  }
}
```

I need to show the returned view into react-native view controller.